# Problem with WCF using namespaces from a DLL component

Tags: .net, wcf

We have a framework here (class library) that has the ordinary operations in a database (CRUD). We also developed two services in WCF to share some of those methods. We choose to let the services hosted each one to a separated Windows Service. Doing this our infra guys can stop only one service without touching the other.

The problem exists on the service that will actually reference those two (let´s call it "client"). Now I have the same class on each reference that I added to the "client" but I can´t send and object received from one WCF Service to the other one because to the "client" , they are two different objects.

Please, take a look at [this image](http://tinypic.com/r/24od7uv/7) maybe it will clear the things out.

I can't get a Person from the Service1 and send it back to the Service2 (compilation error). Do I have to use reflection or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two good options:

- if you want to stick to the current setup, you can use a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) to help you easily copy all property values from one `Person` class to the other - it does so by matching properties on their name, and it works like a charm, really!
- the other option would be to share the commonalities - the service and data contracts - in a separate assembly, so that both your services, as well as the clients, how use and reference the same common assembly. That way, you can avoid the client side creating two separate, new types - both clients would re-use your existing, common, shared assembly's `Person` type, and thus no conversion/auto-mapping would be necessary - the types would be the same for both clients.

  This works as long you you control both ends of the communication (both the service and the client), and both of those are .NET based apps (which I think is the case for you, right?)